# RNAseq tutorial cytoscape

Tags: cytoscape

I am following the tutorial for RNAseq "https://cytoscape.org/cytoscape-tutorials/protocols/rna-seq-data-analysis/#/"

I created an excel file that matches the example data "Transcriptomic analysis of autistic brain reveals convergent molecular pathology". When I paste the Gene ID column in, I am getting an error. My gene ID's are different from the example data because I am working with bacterial genes (I made sure to set the Species idea to this bacterial species).

I am really just looking for a good way to map bacterial RNAseq data in a way that nodes are gene names, organized based on associated pathways/networks and is able to represent the differential expression data.

Thank you

Please see above....

Comment: Hi Alexa -- can you tell us what error you are seeing, and maybe give us an example of your gene list?